# Move character in a sphere

Tags: unity-game-engine, click, move

i want to move the character around a sphere in the click position, i have this code for click in a point and the character moves to that position, the movement its ok but the lookAt method isn't working well.

```
Vector3 targetPosition;
Vector3 lookAtTarget;
Quaternion playerRot;
public float rotSpeed = 20;
public float speed = 10;
public bool move = false;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        SetTargetPosition();
    }

    if (move)
    {
        Move();
    }
}

void SetTargetPosition()
{
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit hit;
    if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 1000))
    {
        targetPosition = hit.point;
        //this.transform.LookAt(targetPosition);
        lookAtTarget = new Vector3(targetPosition.x - transform.position.x, targetPosition.y, targetPosition.z - transform.position.z);
        playerRot = Quaternion.LookRotation(lookAtTarget);

        move = true;
    }
}

void Move()
{
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, playerRot, rotSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, speed * Time.deltaTime);

    if(transform.position == targetPosition)
    {
        move = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you be more precise on "move the character around a sphere"?  If you mean you are walking around on a sphere, then you need to use the LookRotation variant with two arguments, to specify what is the 'up' vector of your player. The one-arg version assumes Vector3.up .

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you use `Vector3.MoveTowards`. This function moves game object to its forward vector.
Split your game object into two parts. make `Mesh Renderer` one, child of another. Assign `MoveToward` script to parent and `LookAt` part to child one.